# next build fails on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a working website on my machine. Next can run it in the development mode and also build in the production one. But the problem is that on the server's machine it raises an error:

```
> Build error occurred
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'serverRuntimeConfig' of 'next_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...)' as it is undefined.
    at Object.aorh (/home/MyInspire-ph.ru-v4/.next/server/pages/
```

Package version is the same, and it does work on my machine. How can I fix it?

Here's my config file

```js
const path = require('path');
const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require('next/constants');

module.exports = phase => {
    return {
        trailingSlash: true,
        images: {
            domain: ['localhost'],
        },
        publicRuntimeConfig: {
            dev: phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER,
        },
        serverRuntimeConfig: {
            rootDir: __dirname.replace(/\\/g, '/'),
            telegram: {
                token: 'sometoken',
                usersFile: 'somefile',
            },
        },
        webpack: config => {
            config.resolve.alias['@sass'] = path.resolve(__dirname, 'sass');
            return config;
        },
    };
};
```

Comment: I suggest you to use Docker.

Comment: It could mean that it is not able to load your `serviceRuntimeConfig` file in the first place, so it cannot destructure it later. Try logging and see if your `serviceRuntimeConfig` file is actually loaded or the path is valid on the server. It doesn't break on your PC as the path or file is available on your PC.

Comment: @Marshal, thank you. The problem was, that `next build` used global package, so `./node_modules/.bin/next build` does it work. And now I only need to know, why it use global one. But anyway it is not relevant to this question